# MySQL 5.7 can't log in with root

Tags: mysql, root

I'm using Debian in a VM and I've tried the method with skip-grant-tables but I still can't log in with "root" user. I've also allowed connection from any IP using the command

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Host='%' WHERE Host='localhost' AND User='username'
```

I've attached a screenshot of the commands I ran after I started sql with skip-grant-tables option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The db format changed since 5.6 so you need to upgrade your tables. Buried within http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html you will find some details. Here is the tl;dr;

First, stop the database if it is running:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Switch to the mysql user to make things easier

```
sudo -u mysql /bin/bash
```

Start up the database in safe mode

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

In another console as root, begin the upgrade

```
sudo su
mysql_upgrade
```

Once that is done, you can stop the safe mode, and go back to live:

```
mysqladmin shutdown
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

From there you can log back in as root and get what you need done.